# Is there a way to transfer data from Time marker 2 to Text console from ucenter? Either Rising or Falling edge values.

Tags: gps, serial-port, hex

I'm using an ublox evk M8T and I'm trying to make a script that shows me in the text console the value of a time marker, which is triggered by a button. So, everytime I press it there would be a time marker that appears. The problem is that that the tm displays values in hex, contrary with the other parameters that are being displayed in txt. How should I proceed so that when I establish the connection with the serial com , to read all the values and when it encounters the hex tm to translate it in a format suitable for text console?